# Copy of an array printing out numbers that the user never input

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have been trying to make a small program which takes in the grades of 5 student, and list out the marks which are over 70.

Here is my code so far, the program has managed to compare the marks, say I enter 70, 66, 99, 81, 1. It will list out 99 and 81, but also for some reason list out 1 and sometimes 32.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;



int main(){


int size = 5;
int marks[size];
int over70[size];




for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

cout<<"Enter the marks of 5 students: "<<endl;
cin>>marks[i];

}

//finding marks over 70

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        if(marks[i] > 70){

        over70[i] = marks[i];
    }

}

//printing out values over 70    

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

    cout<<"First student "<<i+1<<endl;
    cout<<over70[i]<<endl;


}


return 0;

}
```

This is not a homework, but you don't have to give me the answers straight away, I would be more than happy to gets hints or guidance from anyone.

Comment: First, you should initialize your arrays (`marks` and `over70`) Second, notice that `over70` has not the same size of `marks`

Comment: Hint: This is because your "print out" section prints all the over70 array which contain not just the few items that you enter to it (missing certain "if"). Another issue: you need to initialize the variables because they may hold random values.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not C++; start by using the right language. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

> Your `over70` array containing garbage values.

Your array lets 's say have initially 5 garbage values, now when you enter their marks which are less than 70, so other elements of this array will remain garbage value.

So, if the array `over70` contains only marks of two students, you are still printing the whole array, which is expected to show you unexpected values.

What you can do here is count the number of students with marks more than 70, and run the third loop only that many times, so that only those student's marks get printed who have marked more than 70

The answer, in case you want it.

> `int j = 0; 
>  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
>  { 
>      if(marks[i] > 70)
>        { 
>             over70[j] = marks[i]; 
>             j++
>        } 
>  }`
>  // j is the number of students more than 70 marks

Comment: So I tried tweaking my program and I am currently doing if(marks[i] > 70){count++};       but now I am not sure how to initialize my over70 array.

Comment: Initializing means giving some initial value to your variable.

`int marks[5] = { 0 }; // all elements 0`

It will initialize your all elements to zero

Comment: Just saw the hidden answer for a better way of counting elements than just incrementing the count. You can use the index of count70 as its count variable

Comment: It really bothers me that you apparently can't have a multi-line code block in a spoiler tag. (I just tried to edit your answer to remove the ugly backtick formatting, but couldn't get it to work.)

Comment: I am going to try an understand the code. So first we set j = 0 (this will be the size of over70 array), next we do the for loop for the array to loop through every element in marks array to try and find which element has the value of over 70. And if marks[i] > 70 is true, then we make j as over70 array size, lastly we make it so that it equals to the marks[i].

Comment: Few things: j is not the size of over70, its size is 5 as you have made in your program. j is the number of students with marks more than 70, so you can say like that, j is the number of values added to over70 and beyond this, everything is unexpected (garbage values). J only increments when there's a student with marks more than 70, so at least it will give you the number of students with marks more than 70.